# Corona SDK 'camera follow' stop at certain point?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have all my display objects in a group called game. I also have this loop function so a 'camera' effect is created, so the camera follows the ball.

```
local function loop(x)

    local targetx = 600 -ball.x
    game.x = game.x + ((targetx - game.x) *0.05)

end
```

This setup gives a smooth follow of the ball, so the ball is not exactly in the middle of the screen all the time. My question is how to make the game stop following the ball after a certain point. I tried:

```
local function loop(x)
if ball.x < 600 and ball.x > 50 then
    local targetx = 600 -ball.x
    game.x = game.x + ((targetx - game.x) *0.05)
end
end
```

...but it gives a jerky return to following the ball after the ball exits, then returns into the 'following' area (x 50 to 600).

Answer (score 0):

If your loop function is called in a timer, you could easily just cancel the timer / set x to the original x when your ball coordinates are under 50 or above 600.

Answer (score 0):

You might check out [Perspective](http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/perspective) - it's a library solely for virtual camera support for Corona that I wrote.